# How can I edit newly added pinned rows?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm having some issues with ag-grid. I want to click an add row button and add a new row to the top of my grid. To accomplish this I think I need to make use of a temporary pinned row so the item always shows at the top no matter what sorting has been enabled. As soon as the pinned row is added I also want to start editing the row. This is how I'm trying to accomplish this right now, but its not working. If I put a delay in after setting the pinned top row data it works. There has to be a better way to accomplish this.

```
const addRow = () => {
    gridApi.setPinnedTopRowData([myNewItem]);
    gridApi.startEditingCell({
      rowIndex: 0,
      rowPinned: 'top',
      colKey: 'myColumnKey',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a better alternative for you.

In this example, we have a pinned row at the top of the grid. We double click each cell, enter values until the last column and press enter. Voila! A new row has been added to the top!

Beginning

[image: Beginning]

Entering Values

[image: Entering Values]

Final State

[image: Final State]

To achieve that, refer to this blog: https://blog.ag-grid.com/add-new-rows-using-a-pinned-row-at-the-top-of-the-grid/

or refer to my Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pinned-input-row-blog-fzknf4?file=index.js

I have made a minor change in the code of the blog because you wanted the new row to be on top

```
onCellEditingStopped: (params) => {
  if (isPinnedRowDataCompleted(params)) {
    // save data
    setRowData([inputRow, ...rowData]); // minor change
    //reset pinned row
    setInputRow({});
  }
},
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to perform some actions right after pinning row, I have found a grid event: [onPinnedRowDataChanged](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-rowPinning)

Let's give this a try

```
onPinnedRowDataChanged: (params) => {
  gridApi.startEditingCell({
    rowIndex: 0,
    rowPinned: 'top',
    colKey: 'myColumnKey',
  });
},
```

Comment: I appreciate the creativeness here and I've seen this example but it won't work for my use case. I did see that there was an event I could tie into for pinnedrowdatachanged or something that I can listen to and then set my edit for the top pinned row and it works like 70% of the time, however sometimes I still don't get the edit to set correctly.

Comment: If you put the rest of the code after gridApi.setPinnedTopRowData([myNewItem]); inside a settimeout method, everything works fine and you want a better alternative to get rid of settimeout method?

Comment: The event is actually not super predictable it turns out. That is the way I was using it but it seems like after a few row adds it stops going into edit mode automatically. I'll just stick with the setTimeout functionality and see how that performs for me.

Comment: If you can somehow share your code on an online code editor, I may be of help